# comparing oracle date time in query fails and returns no records

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, datetime-format

I am new to oracle and have silly problem comparing dates while selecting records.

I have a field in my tableX called req_datetime which is declared as type DATE

While inserting records I simply use below java formatting and the date is inserted just fine.

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy HH:mm:ss");
```

While I run below query from sql developer it does not return any records , it looks like there is some problem in comparing the date format.I have tried a lot of date formats and none of them worked.

I noticed one thing that if i manually open the table using sql developer and reset the date right away, than the query will return me only row of which I have changed the date using sql developer.

Here is my sql query

```
SELECT * from tableX Where cardno='xyzzz' AND req_datetime >=TO_DATE('11/Jan/2016 00:00:00','dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')  ORDER BY req_datetime ASC
```

please need your help. Thanks
**Updated image:**

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have no uncommited transactions. Your query is correct.

Comment: try comparing it to sysdate and tell me what happens, also, can you give us an example of a date inside the table in the column req_datetime?

Comment: If you select the max(req_datetime) for that cardno, what do you get?

Comment: @ Dan Bracuk -I got date as output 11-01-0016 18:27:17

Comment: @sagi -I have updated the image in my question , that is how date looks to me in sql developer. 
When I used sysdate , i got below error
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

Comment: You appear to be backdating your data by a couple of thousand years.  Also, may you be shot and urinated upon for restoring the horizontal scroll bar to the code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply inserting it with `TO_DATE`? For instance:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table x (req_datetime, ....) VALUES "
      + "(to_date('"+ getCurrentTimeStamp()+ "', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), ...)";
```

with

```
private static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    return dateFormat.format(today.getTime());
}
```

Comment: I would love to do that but it gives me exception when ever i try to insert date in your mentioned format -2016/01/11 19:53:33
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: Better yet, create a datetime object in java and use it as a query paramter.

Comment: @Roger did I miss something above or did it work? Dan's idea is not bad as well: you could use a `?` in the query and bind the parameter. Check example at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InsertDatetimeanddatetimedatatoOracle.htm

Comment: @Trinimon It worked! Thanks a lot for support guys, really appreciate.